# How to override the ::after CSS selector?

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the icon from Hello2 href link while keeping my css code. How to override the a[target="_blank"]:after style ?

HTML:

```
<a class="" href="#" target="_blank">Hello1</a>

<a class="" href="#" target="_blank">Hello2</a>
```

CSS:

```
        a[target="_blank"]:after {
  content:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAQElEQVR42qXKwQkAIAxDUUdxtO6/RBQkQZvSi8I/pL4BoGw/XPkh4XigPmsUgh0626AjRsgxHTkUThsG2T/sIlzdTsp52kSS1wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
      margin: 0 3px 0 5px;
    }
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xbaha/kxdzwro4/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to the second `a` tag and then exclude it from `after` selector using `not`.

```css
a[target="_blank"]:not(.no-icon):after {
      content: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAQElEQVR42qXKwQkAIAxDUUdxtO6/RBQkQZvSi8I/pL4BoGw/XPkh4XigPmsUgh0626AjRsgxHTkUThsG2T/sIlzdTsp52kSS1wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
      margin: 0 3px 0 5px;
    }
```

```html
<a class="" href="#" target="_blank">Hello1</a>
    
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="no-icon">Hello2</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the little icon just after your link, you want to remove it? that's it ?
Try this instead. With this approach, all of your `a` tags with a `target = "_ blank"` attribute will be affected and therefore will appear without the small icon:

CSS

```
a[target="_blank"]:after {content: none;margin: 0 3px 0 5px;}
```

```css
a[target="_blank"]:after {
  content:none;
  margin: 0 3px 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<a class="" href="#" target="_blank">Hello1</a>

<a class="" href="#" target="_blank">Hello2</a>
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, all answers must be in English. Please [edit] your answer and translate it to English.